# How to find the correct location of a .txt file in IPython notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm working in the IPython notebook of a class I'm currently taking. I need to open a .txt file but I'm not sure how to write its location. When I open the IPython notebook there is a folder named students and others named after the lectures. The file I need is on lecture 3's folder. My homework is on a folder with my name inside the students' folder. So what should I write? I tried

```
archivo=open('lecture_3/data/sunspots.txt')
print archivo.read()
archivo.close()
```

but I got "IOERROR: No such file or directory"

Just to give a clear idea of the structure of the IPython notebook of my class, here is the basic structure.

```
-Students
 --My_name 
  ---my_homeworks
    ----this_particular_homework (this is where I need to read the .txt file)
 -Lecture_1
 -Lecture_2
 -Lecture_3
  --data (this is where the .txt file is)
 -Lecture_4 and so on
```

Also, how can I make sure the .txt file is there? I can't see it from IPython.

I'm very new to IPython, so apologies for any mistakes.

Comment: archivo is spanish for file

Comment: did you try "./lecture_3/data/sunspots.txt" ?

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work.